# Play music with PyGame without display

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm trying to get music to play using pygame, but I don't want the GUI to pop up. If I comment out the screen variable it doesn't work, but if I leave it in everything works fine (except there is the display which I don't want).

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1,1))
pygame.mixer.music.load("01 Twisted Coil.mp3")
print("Loading Music...")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this library like so:

```
pip install mp3play
```

Then load a file and play it:

```
import mp3play

sound = mp3play.load('sound.mp3')
sound.play()
```

Comment: Well, now that I know this library exists.....perfect! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @ThomasLamanna Please mark as answer if this was helpful to you.